# How does the DatabaseMetaData getTables method work?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am using MySQL driver and I have schema called `testschema` and 3 tables there - `tab1`, `test_test1`, `test_test2`. I have some doubts about using getTables method from DatabaseMetaData:

1. For metaData.getTables(null, "testschema", "\\\"tab1\\\"", null); no table is returned. Is it desired behaviour? If so, why? I am escaping quote characters so output should be the same as for metaData.getTables(null, "testschema", "tab1", null); - in this case table description is returned.
2. For metaData.getTables(null, "testschema", "test%", null); no tables are returned, but for metaData.getTables("testschema", "testschema", "test%", null); both `test_test1` and `test_test2` are returned. Why I need catalog parameter specified in this case?

Comment: Why do you think adding double quotes are allowed (they are not, unless the double quotes is actually part of the table name), and if so, why are you double escaping the backslash?

Answer (score 1):

When you write actual SQL, the double quote can be used **in SQL**, which is a different kind of programming language, to basically state: The thing in the quotes is an identifier (table name, column name, view name, index name - some sort of name of an object). Do not uppercase it first, don't try to see if it's an SQL keyword.

The `getTables` call **is not SQL**. Thus, you're asking for a table that is literally named `"tab1"`, quotes and all, which obviously doesn't exist, hence why you won't get any results there. Whether `getTables` attempts to do normalization (generally, uppercasing) is up to the DB engine; a few do but many don't. If you write it in the proper casing (so, all uppercase if the `CREATE TABLE` statement that made the thing didn't use quotes at all, otherwise precisely what was within the quotes of the `CREATE TABLE "tableNameHere"` statement that made the table) - then you'll definitely get the result back, otherwise, if you have the same characters but with different casing, you may or you may not, depends on the SQL engine, JDBC library used to access it, version of both of those, and the phase of the moon.

The javadoc of [`DatabaseMetaData`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html) **explicitly** calls out that `%` and `_` have special meaning for any strings where the docs call that string a `somethingPattern`, where "something" can be whatever, obviously. This is the case here, hence why `"test%"` does find things. Not because `test%` is what SQL's `LIKE` operation uses, just because the spec says so.

Speaking of specs, if truly it is the case that:

```
meta.getTables(null, "X", "Y", null);
```

fails to find things that:

```
meta.getTables("foo", "X", "Y", null);
```

does find, then **the mysql JDBC implementation is broken** and you should perhaps file a bug report. In general MySQL is a cavalcade of weird choices (so weird, you may as well call them bugs; at some point documenting insane behaviour doesn't magically make it a non-bug, though i'm mincing words, perhaps) - and actual bugs.

So, why do you need that catalog parameter? Because MySQL is bad. Use postgres, maybe. It's slightly less crazy, and you have a choice of JDBC drivers. (postgres's own, and PGJDBC-NG).

Comment: "Thus, you're asking for a table that is literally named "tab1", quotes and all, which obviously doesn't exist" - when we escape `"\\\"tab1\\\""` then I am not asking for "tab1", but for `\"tab1\"`. So if we would change getTables behaviour to make CREATE TABLE statement instead then it would be something like this: `CREATE TABLE \"tab1\"`, is it right? I still don't understand why we can escape `_` and `%` in getTables pattern, but we can't escape quoting... If I will set tablePattern to `"test%"` then I will get both tables returned but for `"test\\%"` I'll get none so escaping works here.

Comment: And how I should search for table `test_test1` to avoid using `_` as wildcard but just treat it as a normal char? So I want to find this table but without using wildcards

Comment: Your table is not named `"tab1"` with quotes. Trust me. It's perhaps called `tab1` - and that _requires_ `CREATE TABLE "tab1"` (and if you do that in java, the quotes would be backslash-escaped), because `CREATE TABLE tab1` makes a table called `TAB1`. The quotes are __not__ part of the table name.

Comment: You can escape % and _ because the spec says so. You can't do the quotes thing because the spec doesn't mention that part.

Comment: Read the javadoc more closely, it explains how to escape _ and %.

Comment: _"Whether getTables attempts to do normalization (generally, uppercasing) is up to the DB engine"_. It is not up to the engine or driver, the JDBC specification says it must match as it is stored in the metadata tables of the underlying database. That said, some drivers do - incorrectly and contravening the specification - try to do some tricks.